# How to call component's activated hook from mounted/created

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I want to call activated hook from mounted - I'm using same piece of code as a view and a child component, and activated is called only when I'm using it as a view - so I've decided to call activated from mounted for component-scenario. Any way to do that?

Comment: The life cycle hooks are meant to be called by Vue's system and allow you to execute some custom logic. I think invoking a lifecycle hook from another hook is a misuse. If I may, what is it are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, you make a good point, I guess it'd be better if I put the logic in activated into a separate method. I have a sub-view that contains list of items. In other view, I want to open the same list of items in a modal - decided to do that by reusing the view by adding a prop(indicating modal-mode) and showing/hiding certain fields according to that prop.

Comment: "decided to do that by reusing the view" - the subview, you mean? Makes much more sense. Hack a sample and post back results/problems, if any.